# Нужно отметить нарушения синтаксических норм

Tags: синтаксис

*Я ценю хороших людей, которые встречаются мне в жизни.*

Answer (score 1):

*Я ценю **хороших людей**, которые встречаются мне в жизни.*

Мне кажется, что здесь есть семантическая погрешность. В предложении говорится, что ценятся только хорошие люди, а не все.

Вариант правки: *Людей, которые мне встречаются в жизни, я ценю з**а честность, доброту, за хорошие поступки**...*

Comment: По-моему, в этом и смысл предложения: некто ценит именно хороших людей.

Comment: Да? Но это же неправильно!  А остальных не ценит, пока не убедится, что они хорошие.  И где тогда ошибка?

Comment: Это просто предложение без контекста, какое дело нам до любой другой правильности, кроме связанной с русским языком? // Где запрошенная синтаксическая ошибка, не знаю.

Comment: Что значит какое? Семантическая ошибка – это конкретный термин, их виды даже перечисляются.

Comment: Я ценю людей, которых встречаю в своей жизни.  Союзное слово "который" должно быть в род.пад.

Comment: @Серж, а почему И.п. грамматически неверен, может, это просто разные варианты записи. Чем они отличаются по смыслу или по стилю?

Comment: Союзное слово"который" согласовывается по роду, числу и падежу. Нарушена грамматическая связь. Ср.: людей, которые я встречаю... Вы же так не скажете. Дело не в стилистики.

Comment: Согласуются в роде и числе, но НЕ В ПАДЕЖЕ. Падеж союзного слова определяется в придаточном предложении, а там "которые" – это подлежащее (И. п.). Грамматическая основа: которые встречаются. Сравнить: Я знаю тех людей, о которых ты говоришь. Здесь союзное слово в роли дополнения, П.п. Ваше предложении: Я ценю людей, которых (я) встречаю в своей жизни.  Здесь подлежащее пропущено, союзное слово в роли дополнения, Р. п.